# Elevation source published by GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, dted

I want to read dted files by arcgis runtime sdk .net. DTED files are published by GeoServer. I am looking for the function to read the elevation values.

RasterElevationSource is used to read the local dted files.
ArcgisTiledElevationSource is used to read the dted files that are published by Arcgis Server. So, which function to use to read the dted files published by GeoServer?

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. Additionally, is it same for WMTS? Since I am using WMTS.

Comment: a WMTS is just a striped down WMS

Answer (score 0):

As Ian correctly points out, WMS is meant to return data representations, not data itself (that would be the job of WCS).

However, this alone has not stopped people from being creative and building an output format that actually returns raw data: the [DDS/BIL community module](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/dds/index.html).

It was originally written to serve DEMs to WorldWind, nowadays my company is using it to serve DEMs to CesiumJS instead.